# Woocommerce shopping cart displays but wont take me to Cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shopping-cart, product

I have a problem with the woocommerce shopping cart icon, it does display and counts products but when I click it, its like nothing happened. It redirects me to the same page I am. It is supposed to take me to /cart/ isn't it?

[image]

Comment: Can you give your site link? It may be a theme bug.

Comment: What theme are you using? It seems like a theme bug in theme mini-cart script. Best thing to do is to contact theme authors, opening a thread or a ticket support.